# CSS styling for input tags inside labels

Tags: css, input, filter, label, mixitup

I am using the below filter to sort a list:

```
 <fieldset class="groups">
  <h4 class="cufon_headings">Groups</h4>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="member1">
    <label>Member 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="member2">
      Member 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="member3">
      Member 3</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

This is my CSS for the above filter:

```
/* Checkbox Styles*/
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.checkbox{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.checkbox label{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.checkbox label:before,
.checkbox label:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.checkbox label:before{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.checkbox label:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #E50082;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.checkbox input:checked ~ label:after{
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox input:focus ~ label:before{
  background: #eee;
}
```

The first checkbox (Member 1) is correctly styled, i.e. checking the first option marks the checkbox magenta. In this example the  tag is outside of the  tags.

The other chekcbox options (Member 2 and Member 3) do not turn magenta upon selecting them. With both the  tag is inside the  tag.

The preferred variant is having the  tags inside the  tags. However, I could not figure out how to adapt the CSS to get this working. Can anyone provide help? (Here is a link to [the code on CopePen](https://codepen.io/friiitz/pen/vKkNvK))

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset class="groups">
  <h4 class="cufon_headings">Groups</h4>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="member1">
    <label>Member 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">

      <input type="checkbox" value="member2">
      <label>Member 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">

      <input type="checkbox" value="member3">
      <label>Member 3</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Make sure that your labels are correct for member 2 and 3. You had the label tag including the input tag. The code above seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Charlie's answer is correct. In CSS, you can't affect a parent - only a child.

`before` and `after` are puesdo elements and they're not exactly acting like normal elements, so they're not siblings of `input`.

In order to solve your problem, Change every:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="memberN">
        Member N
    </label>
</div>
```

Into:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="memberN">
    <label>
        Member N
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. It was intended that the first checkbox differs from the others to show the effect.

If it is not possible with CSS I guess I need to adapt how the plugin Contact Form 7 for Wordpress gives out the HTML for checkboxes. Not the preferred way to handle the issue.